# get all data from mogoDB database instead of a single collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have two collections in my DB

```
const FastFood = mongoose.model("fast-food", foodSchema)
const Liquid = mongoose.model("liquid", foodSchema)
```

both of them have whole bunch of data inside. i want to get a data like:

```
{
    fast-food: {
        //data here
    },
    liquid: {
        // data here
    }
}
```

`await FastFood.find({})`this code returns only data in `fast-food` but i want all.i dont want to write one by one like

```
await FastFood.find({})
await Liquid.find({})
and so on.
```

is there any way of achieving this. smth like `myDB.getallData()` which return all data inside. Thank You!

Using mongoose by the way

Comment: its possible to use `Promise.all` ?

Comment: Use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)